# Running rails console command from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to spawn rails console from nodejs and then execute the script in rails console ?

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const child_process = spawn('rails c');

child_process.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout', data.toString());
});

child_process.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr', data);
});

child_process.on('close', function (code) {
  console.log('close', code);
});
```

Upon opening the console, i wanted to execute this script in the rails console

```rb
user_id = 1624522827
Sharding.get_shard(user_id) do
  account = UserList::User.find(user_id).make_user
end
```

How to achieve this in nodejs. My intention is to create a cli that runs script inside rails console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `rails runner` instead of console.  Either pass it a line of ruby code or a filename.  It will run in the rails environment, not just the ruby irb environment.

Answer (score 0):

The ruby console is for humans. I wouldn't try and pipe input into it.

A better idea is to use a rake task and then call that with

`bundle exec rake task:subtask`

[guide for rake tasks](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/02/ruby-rake/)

All your code should go in the rake task and then you can call it from nodejs using just the filepath.